# How to pass external JSON data to the task from file that generating in previous task?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, variables, gruntjs

I'm stuck here with this one.
I've got gruntfile with this type of tasks:

```
grunt.initConfig({

  shell: {
    // stub task; do not really generate anything, just copy to test
    copyJSON: {
      command: 'mkdir .tmp && cp stub.json .tmp/javascripts.json'
    }
  },

  uglify: {
    build: {
      files: {
        'output.min.js': grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/javascripts.json')
      }
    }
  },

  clean: {
    temp: {
      src: '.tmp'
    }
  }
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
  'shell:copyJSON',
  'uglify:build',
  'clean:temp'
]);
```

And, of cource, this is don’t work, because there is no `.tmp/javascripts.json` file:

```
Error: Unable to read ".tmp/javascripts.json" file (Error code: ENOENT).
```

I’ve try to do extra task what creating the variable after file is generated, tried to store it at `globals.javascript` and `grunt.option("JSON")`, like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('exportJSON', function() {
    if (grunt.file.exists('.tmp/javascripts.json')) {
        grunt.log.ok("JSON with set of javascripts exist");
        grunt.option("JSON", grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/javascripts.json'));
    }
    else {
        grunt.fail.warn("JSON with set of javascripts does not exist");
    };
});

grunt.initConfig({
    uglify: {
        build: {
            files: {
                'output.min.js': grunt.option("JSON")
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'shell:copyJSON',
    'exportJSON',
    'uglify:build',
    'clean:temp'
]);
```

And always have a same error `Warning: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined Use --force to continue.`

Do not really know how to figure this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to populate a configuration option to be resolved only at the point in time that it is run you'll need to use templates:

http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates

So simply put you need to change the `uglify` task's `files` configuration to the following:

```
files: {
    'output.min.js': "<%= grunt.option('JSON') %>"
}
```

There is also the option of changing the configuration of the `uglify` task using `grunt.config.set`:

```
grunt.registerTask('exportJSON', function() {
    if (grunt.file.exists('.tmp/javascripts.json')) {
        grunt.log.ok("JSON with set of javascripts exist");
        files = grunt.file.readJSON('.tmp/javascripts.json');
        grunt.config.set(
            ['uglify', 'build', 'files', 'output.min.js'], files
        );
    } else {
        grunt.fail.warn("JSON with set of javascripts does not exist");
    }
});
```

In which case the your `uglify` task's `files` option needs to be something like:

```
files: {
    'output.min.js': ''
}
```

Comment: "<%= grunt.config.set('awesome',true) %>"

Comment: In the context of the provided example, or are you actually trying to use it in a template string?

Comment: I _was_ trying to use it in a template string.  I didn't work for the case I had.  I found a couple of work arounds though. https://github.com/werk85/grunt-ng-constant/issues/43